# getting wrong output in bisection method

Tags: python, bisection

I have created the following code which does the bisection method.

I am trying to use it to find the root for the function f(x)=x^7-6x^6-28x^5+232x^4-336x^3-544x^2+1728x-1152 on the interval [1, 3.1].

I have been given a hint that x_0 = 2 is a root for this function on the interval. I am getting that there is no root, and I was hoping someone could help me fix this!

Here's my code below:

```
import math
import numpy as np
def root(x):
    return (x**7-6*x**6-28*x**5+232*x**4-336*x**3-544*x**2+1728*x-1152)

def bisection_method(f, a, b, tol):
    if f(a)*f(b) > 0:
        #end function, no root.
        print("No root found.")
    else:
        iter = 0
        while (b - a)/2.0 > tol:
            midpoint = (a + b)/2.0

            if f(a)*f(midpoint) < 0: # Increasing but below 0 case
                b = midpoint
            else:
                a = midpoint

            iter += 1
        return(midpoint, iter)

answer, iterations = bisection_method(root, 1, 3.1, 10**(-14))
print("Answer:", answer, "\nfound in", iterations, "iterations")
```

This is the output I am getting:

```
No root found.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-ecdc56120415> in <module>()
 21         return(midpoint, iter)
 22 
---> 23 answer, iterations = bisection_method(root, 1, 3.1, 10**(-14))
 24 print("Answer:", answer, "\nfound in", iterations, "iterations")

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: The bisection method, as it is usually defined, cannot find the root at x=2 because that root is actually a local maximum. The function is always negative around x=2.

Comment: @JamesKPolk so I cant solve this function?

Comment: Not if you insist on using the bisection method to find a root in [1, 3.1]. However, the bisection method should work to find a root in [3, 9]. Except your code is buggy I think.

Comment: so I guess I cant graph the absolute error vs the number of iterations it on this interval

Comment: Your code correctly performs no iterations, it instead prints "No root found." and returns `None`, which you then try to unpack into two variables causing the exception.

Comment: how would I fix this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183158/discussion-between-james-k-polk-and-user123).